# how to search matching data in latest file using azure search in blob container c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search

I have azure blob container named `dataTest` inside that have `multiple folders created based on year/ month / date.`

```
dataTest/rawjson/2019/01/25/01/demo1.json

dataTest/rawjson/2018/12/30/02/demo2.json
```

I want to get the file from latest folder path would be-

```
dataTest/rawjson/2019/01/25/01/demo1.json
```

How do I get the latest path `(dataTest/rawjson/2019/01/25/01/demo1.json)`

when I pass input as `dataTest/rawjson`

I want to read data using `azure search` we need to create a `index` by importing this blob container.

I wonder is there any way to pass this blob path dynamically and get the latest file data using `azure search`?

before `azure search` i was using below c# code to get latest file

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("dataTest");

            string directoryreference = "dataTest/rawjson/events";

            var blobDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(directoryreference);
            IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> items = blobDirectory.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);

            string blobFilePath = String.Empty;
            foreach (var blob in items.OfType<CloudBlob>()

    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Properties.LastModified))
            {
                string blobFileFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(blob.Name).Replace("\\", "/");
                blobFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(blobFileFullPath).Replace("\\", "/");
                if (blobFilePath != null)
                { break; }

            }
            var blobFileDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(blobFilePath);
            IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> fileitems = blobFileDirectory.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no physical folder in blobs, the "folder" is just part of the path to the blob. .Each IListBlobItem is going to be a CloudBlockBlob, a CloudPageBlob, or a CloudBlobDirectory.

After casting to block or page blob, or their shared base class CloudBlob (preferably by using the as keyword and checking for null), you can access the modified date via blockBlob.Properties.LastModified.

Note that your implementation will do an O(n) scan over all blobs in the container, which can take a while if there are hundreds of thousands of files. There's currently no way of doing a more efficient query of blob storage though, (unless you abuse the file naming and encode the date in such a way that newer dates alphabetically come first). Realistically if you need better query performance I'd recommend keeping a database table handy that represents all the file listings as rows, with things like an indexed DateModified column to search by and a column with the blob path for easy access to the file.

A better approach would be to make use of Azure Table Storage along with blob storage. In this approach, when a blob is created you write an entry into Azure Table Storage. Also when a blob is updated, you make another entry into Azure Table Storage. This was you will be able to build an audit trail.

If you're interested in keeping a history of blobs (for example user uploaded a text file and then uploaded another text file and you want to keep track of both text files contents), then what you could do is take a snapshot of the blob before it is being updated. What it will do is create a read-only copy of the existing blob. When a snapshot is created, the process returns you a date/time value that you can store along with your updated entry in table storage.